# Modifying common keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu [14.04]

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I need to modify the [Common Applicaton Shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts#Common_application_shortcuts) in Ubuntu 14.04 so I can use the Super (Windows) key instead of Ctrl. I looked them up in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts but there are no options to change them.

How can I have the Super key replace the Ctrl in these shorcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**     Download Autokey from either the Ubuntu Software Center or use the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

**Step 2:**     Open Autokey (search AutoKey in dash menu)

**Step 3:**     Create a New Top-Level Folder from File ► New ► Folder

**Step 4:**     Select Folder and create New Script from File ► New ►Script

**Step 5:**      In the "# Enter script code" enter 
`keyboard.send_keys("shortcut you desire to imitate")`

Examples

1. `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<v>")`
2. `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<c>")`
3. `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<s>")`

***Note*** : repeat Step 4-5 for each hotkey you want to add

**Step 6:** Click on the second <kbd>set</kbd> on the Hotkey and set your hotkey

**Step 7:** Save and test them out.It should work now.

Extra Stuff

Enable automatically start Autokey at login (Edit ► preferences ► general) , clear the special hotkeys (Edit ► preferences ► Special Hotkeys) and we are done.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try the following; system settings  keyboard  shortcuts
there are many options there to set all sorts of key combinations.
Sorry, I see now you've already tried that.
I just went and tried it myself and it works;  if you select the shortcut you want to change and click on it the words "new accellerator" appear, you then hold the super key and whichever you want in combination with it and it sets the combination.